# Logging in Ruby/Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, logging

I have the following code:

```
  def get_request(resource)
    request = Typhoeus::Request.new("#{@BASE_URL}#{resource}",
                                    userpwd: "#{@USER}:#{@PWD}",
                                    headers: { 'Content-Type' => "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"})
    response = request.run.body
    puts response
  end
```

Instead of `puts response`, I want to log the entire `response`. What's the best/most efficient way to do that? Regardless of what `response` is, it should be logged. I feel like opening a file, writing to it and closing it every time this method is used would be pretty inefficient. Is there a better way?

Comment: use `Rails.logger.info response` instead of `puts` [Rails logging](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `Rails` as the tag supposes, you can use

```
Rails.logger
```

to use the default `Rails` logger. Here's an example.

```
Rails.logger.info response.body
```